# Get Screen with the mouse cursor on it

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2013, screen

I'm making a little screenshot application. Anything is working so far.
Now I want to add multiScreen support. I want a key that makes a screenshot of the active monitor (with the mouse cursor on it).

I thought about calculating the Rectangle of all screens, get the cursor possition and calculate on which monitor the coordinates are. But I have don't get it work!

Can anyone provide me a code snippet? Thank you

Comment: [FromPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.frompoint.aspx)?

Comment: @Sinatr Thank you! That's exactly what I searched!